# Bind MenuItems dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to bind `MenuItem` dynamically.

I have `public List<string> LastOpenedFiles { get; set; }` is my data source.
My command that I try to run is `public void DoLogFileWork(string e)`

```
<MenuItem Header="_Recent..."
          ItemsSource="{Binding LastOpenedFiles}">
  <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
      <Setter Property="Header"
              Value="What should be here"></Setter>
      <Setter Property="Command"
              Value="What should be here" />
      <Setter Property="CommandParameter"
              Value="What should be here" />
    </Style>
  </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

I want on each entry from `LastOpenedFiles` is I click on it to go to  `DoLogFileWork` function with the entry value that I clicked on.

Thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Setter Property="Header" Value="What should be here"></Setter>
```

Nothing, you've already set this above to `_Recent...`

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="What should be here"/>
<Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="What should be here"/>
```

Are you using a MVVM approach? If so, you'll need an `ICommand` exposed on the ViewModel that the Window/Control is bound to, take a look at the `RelayCommand` mentioned in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) (or is native in VS2012 I believe).

This is the sort of thing you'd setup in your VM:

```
    private RelayCommand _DoLogFileWorkCommand;
    public RelayCommand DoLogFileWorkCommand {
        get {
            if (null == _DoLogFileWorkCommand) {
                _DoLogFileWorkCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    (param) => true,
                    (param) => { MessageBox.Show(param.ToString()); }
                );
            }
            return _DoLogFileWorkCommand;
        }
    }
```

Then in your Xaml:

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ElementName=wnLastOpenedFiles, Path=DataContext.DoLogFileWorkCommand}" />
<Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
```

So here, you're binding the `Command` of the `MenuItem` to be the `DoLogFileWorkCommand` declared above, and `CommandParameter` is being bound to the string in the List that the MenuItem is bound to.